# How to push to detail view controller on button click by didselectrow manually; get back again and then push as count of data source array?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

I have a uitable view and I want to perform didselectrow manually on button action; then next view controller is pushed. Take their a screen shot and get back. Again perfom this action till data source counts?
Any sample logic or objective c code ?

The scenerio is : 
1. Click on UIButton to start didselectrow manually. 
2. Index 1 of uitabel view is selected ; next view controller will be presented; here it takes a screenshot and then get back. 
3. Then it shows next view controller as of uitable's 2nd indexpath.row; again takes screenshot and get pop to previous view controller. 
4. This scenerio continues till all indexes view controller displayed and got thier screen shot

Comment: "till data source counts" what is that supposed to mean? What are you asking for? taking screenshots, pushing view controllers, something about data sources, invoking didSelectRow via code!? You need to be more specific in describing what you are trying to achieve and provide some code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: The scenerio is :
1. Click on UIButton to start didselectrow manually. 
2. Index 1 of uitabel view is selected ; next view controller will be presented; here it takes a screenshot and then get back.
3. Then it shows next view controller as of uitable's 2nd indexpath.row; again takes screenshot and get pop to previous view controller.
4. This scenerio continues till all indexes view controller displayed and got thier screen shot

Comment: ... why? is there any user interaction or are you building an app that just does stuff without the user? Anyway: provide some code for your 4 objectives and provide detailed information what is not working with said code...

Comment: No, the app. has to take different screen shots of details of items of uitable view. There is a long list of items and user clicks once to get all screenshots? I dont have code yet any logic but needs to create it. I have used assets Libereray to take screen shot and save uiimages to a custom album. But now i have to convert it automated. Needs someone assistance.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach,if you want to do didSelect on UITableView manually then store your indexpath.row value in your Cell's Button Tag.

Now, in your button action call the didSelect of tableView as per button tag.

**Demo Code:-**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:btn.tag inSection:0]
[self tableView:playListTbl didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I have mentioned all my scenerio in the previous answer's comment. Please have a review of it. Answer is appreciated.

Comment: You must write your question in a proper way, before expecting an answer of your choice.I have answered it as per your question.